# Can a chemical reaction cause a cigarette to taste bad?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I'm currently researching an idea where I'd like to find out if there is any chemical we can put in toothpaste that would react badly with tobacco smoke?

The idea is that smokers can just brush their teeth as anyone would normally do, but when they light up a cigarette it would taste awful. So the actual question is, of all the stuff that's in tobacco, is there anything we can make react that is

1. safe to put in toothpaste.
2. reacts solely by giving a bad taste.
3. doesn't let that bad taste last for longer than 10 minutes.

I just want to know if this is technically possible since I don't have a background in chemistry. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm afraid this is not going to work, even if the combination of tobacco smoke and toothpaste would produce an awful taste. Cigarettes themselves already taste nasty, but it is tolerated by the consumer's body because of nicotine dose is delivered and organism makes it feel like it was worth it. The same will happen with the toothpaste. The only possibility that still works in an absence of willpower is the nicotine patches which are gradually decreasing nicotine addiction. You need to tackle the root of the problem and not the symptoms.

Comment: Thanks for answering! The idea came to us since most stop-smoking products that are out there actually taste nasty themselves or require an extra effort. And although to a non-smoker a cigarette is nasty either way, to a smoker actually enjoys the taste (I myself am a smoker) The principle itself is actually based on classic conditioning, a method that has proven it's worth, since the entire western civilization is based on it. (e.c.:If you steal, you go to jail.) The question I am trying to find an answer to is whether it is or is not chemically possible.

Comment: You can find a list of the components of tobacco smoke on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobacco_smoke). They are all several ng only. I would guess that tobacco smoke could lead to an oxidizing environment, so maybe that would be a starting point (e.g. silver spoon + egg -> bad taste). But I would fear that other food could contain similar ingredients,so that it wouldn't be really specific. You would probably want something to react on a specific ingredient of tobacco smoke, but in ng range it would be difficult.

Comment: I can sympathize with your lack of a "background in chemistry", but the question is really kinda broad. Good question, but that doesn't change the fact that it is too broad for this forum and hence should be closed as such. **However**, if you take user @deus 's cue and (try) zeroing down on a particular compound which can be "studied" by other users, it would greatly improve the question. Intriguing idea by the way; have an upvote! +1 ;)

Comment: The problem with conditioning is that it works both ways. The smoker will simply condition themselves away from the bad-tasting toothpaste. (Also, any toothpaste effect should wear of by lunchtime at the latest.)

Comment: There exist a commercial product sold in form of liquid. A drop of it on the tongue makes smoking almost impossible. You should be able to find it in the web as for it exist for sure. Saw a demonstration at Manchester airport. My friend tried. I, after him, did not because I wanted to smoke one cigarette before entering the non smoking zones....!